# Remove li from ul with jquery from href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, listitem

I want to remove all `<li>` row but instead I removing the tag`<a>`. 
I just try `$(this).closest('li').remove()` but dont work also try `li.remove()`. I have this:

```
$("#demo").append("<li  class='list-group-item'>" + result.Num+ " - " + result.Desc+ "<a onclick='$(this).remove()' href='#'class='pull-right'> Delete</a> </li>");
```

Comment: Rory's code has to work,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct method to solve your problem is to use `$(this).closest('li').remove()` to traverse to the nearest parent `li` to the clicked `a` and remove it. Note that you will need to escape the quotes within the string, which is the only reason I can see why what you tried would not work.

```
$("#demo").append('<li class="list-group-item">' + result.Num + ' - ' + result.Desc + '<a onclick="$(this).closest(\'li\').remove()" href="#" class="pull-right">Delete</a></li>');
```

However a much better approach is to use a delegated event handler instead of outdated `on*` event attributes, like this:

```
var $demo = $("#demo").append('<li class="list-group-item">' + result.Num + ' - ' + result.Desc + '<a href="#" class="pull-right">Delete</a></li>');
$demo.on('click', '.list-group-item a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks... @Rory McCrossan